# Creating new facebook app and restricting access

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps

i  m developing a new app and have followed instructions similar to here..
[Restricting page tab app to only fans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658941/restricting-page-tab-app-to-only-fans)

so indeed my app when accessed from corresponding page only loads as soon as it is "liked"
that's great..
the problem is, that what happens if someone attempts to access the app directly and not through the corresponding fan page..
is there any way to restrict app so that it is not shown standalone but only through the fan page??
cause it seems when it is access directly, the page -> liked is not working, so nothing is "done..

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your application is opened from Facebook fan page, you receive [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/). If you didn't get signed_request, you can simply redirect user to your application on Facebook.

Comment: I ll try this right now..so I guess I ll add another condition liked 0 / 1 or null?

Comment: I don't think new condition is necessary. You just need to check if you received that signed_request or not. If you're worried someone might send you wake signed_request to get around it, in the link i provided is example of how to validate signed request. But the most simple solution would be `if(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']))`